# Fastest way to extract same member in a list of instances of the same class

Tags: python, performance, list, class

This is a high performance Python question:

My colleague gave me a list lFoos of instances of class Foo.

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self): 
    stuff
    ...
    self.spam = random number
    ....
```

The list is huge and all I care about is the *spam* element in each instance. I want to put them in a list. Right now I do this which works fine but slow:

```
mySpams = [None] * len(lFoos)
for myFoo in range(len(lFoos)):
    mySpams[myFoo] = lFoos[myFoo].spam
```

The question is how to make this fast.

Comment: You are using *lists* not *arrays*. The typical idioms don't involve matrializing a list of `None`s and then assigning to each index, instead, build a list starting with an empty list `mySpams = []`, then in your loop grow the list using `mySpams.append(<something>)`. Then, you can use list-comprehensions which are essentially syntactic sugar for the previous idiom, with some optimizations that allow it to perform marginally faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, val):
         self.val = val
lFoo = [Foo(i) for i in range(1000)]
%timeit [f.val for f in lFoo]

10000 loops, best of 3: 52.5 µs per loop

%timeit list(map(lambda f: f.val, lFoo))

10000 loops, best of 3: 114 μs per loop
```

Comment: That's insane. I didn't know you could achieve so much with lambda.

Comment: You can do a lot of stuff with lambdas, map, folds etc. However in general it will be probably faster to do them with comprehensions. The extra function call that the lambda incurs is a big penalty in python. Also Guido van Rossum (python's creator) believes python should do away with these functional concepts

Answer (score 4):

You may use a *list comprehension* to extract the *spam* property of each `Foo` object in `lFoos` list as:

```
new_list = [foo_obj.spam for foo_obj in lFoos]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you could be any faster than the following:

```
[foo.spam for foo in lFoos]
```